# How to add tooltip to a non hyperlink HTML tag

Tags: html, css, tooltip

Is there anyways to add tooltips to a non hyper link?

ie . I want to have a mouse over tooltip when it goes over a text
I would appreciate a working  example of tooltip that is not based on a hyperlink

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If by tooltip you mean the `title` attribute, you can apply that to a lot of different HTML elements. For example `span`:

```
<span title="This is my tooltip">roll over me!</span>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/cBHf7/

---

However if you're referring to javascript tooltips, then these can also be applied to elements other than the anchor:

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/

Comment: My answer looks like I've just copied both Matt & Joe's answers and made a hybrid of the two! I can assure you both I didn't see these until posting :)

Comment: :) That is the nature of these kinds of boards.

Answer (score 1):

```
<span title="this is the tooltip">Text user will see on page goes here</span>
```

You can add a title attribute to almost all HTML tags like this, apart from `<base>, <head>, <html>, <meta>, <param>, <script>, <style>`, and `<title>`. More info from W3Schools [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_title.asp).

There are various JavaScript options available, the advantage of which is that you can alter the syling e.g. make the tooltip bigger, or add line breaks in the text. The downside is that it's more complex to implement and might impact on page responsiveness if you have lots. Your call :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many jQuery plugins that will accommodate this behavior.  You can tooltip on jQuery selectors.  Or just use the "title" attribute.

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/