# Specify title attribute within rst

Tags: restructuredtext

I would like to specify a descriptive "title" attribute that shows up in html when I convert my rst over but I don't know what syntax to use. Any help? Is this already implemented within rst?

Clarifiaction: I want a title attribute within an "a" tag so that when I hover over the link, the title shows up.

Answer (score 0):

This is from [the reStructuredText primer](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickstart.html):

> To indicate the document title in reStructuredText, use a unique adornment style at the beginning of the document. To indicate the document subtitle, use another unique adornment style immediately after the document title.

For example:

```
================
 Document Title
================
----------
 Subtitle
----------

Section Title
=============
```

Comment: Please see the clarification, I need a title attribute within a link "a" tag so that when I hover over the link text, the title shows up.

Comment: Regardless of how you could accomplish this in reST, what would be the corresponding attribute for the "a" tag? How would this implemented in HTML? Because I am under the impression that HTML no longer supports such "tooltip" behaviour.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realize tooltips are not supported in html. Thanks for the help. This is a moot point then

Comment: It seems there is. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995542/how-to-add-tooltip-to-a-non-hyperlink-html-tag